# How do you shift the tab positions dynamically with jQuery Accordian?

Tags: jquery

In Accordion jQuery functionality, how do you shift the tab positions dynamically using left, right, top and bottom without using UI plugin?

Example: There is a drop down with four values these are 1.top 2.bottom 3.left and 4.right

```
If i click on top -    Tabs should display top to bottom direction
If i click on bottom - Tabs should display bottom to top direction
If i click on left -   Tabs should display left to right direction
If i click on left -   Tabs should display right to left direction
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by left to right direction and right to left direction? an accordion is vertical.

Comment: Assume there are 4 tabs,i.e Tab1,Tab2,Tab3 and Tab4  they are arranged  from top to bottom this will be by default   and if i select bottom it should display from bottom to top that is tab4 to tab1   and left it should display left to right from tab1 to tab4     if i click right it should display riht to left from tab4 to tba1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. Note that this code is not complete. You need to add all cases...

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });

    switch (str) {
    case 'top':
        $("#tabs").addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
        break;

    case 'bottom':
        // fix the classes
        $( ".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav, .tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav > *" )
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all ui-corner-top" )
            .addClass( "ui-corner-bottom" );

        // move the nav to the bottom
        $( ".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav" ).appendTo( ".tabs-bottom" );
        break;

    case 'left':
        // change the required classes
        break;

    case 'right':
        // change the required classes
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: can u plese provide me what are these   ui-tabs-vertical  and ui-helper-clearfix and similar classes.

Comment: These are the classes used by the jQuery tabs plugin. You can find these classes in [jQuery tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#bottom). Check the source code for the example in the page (jQuery tabs documentation).

Comment: Hi,In this example when i select a value from select drop down, selected value is not coming to switch case..its showing NAN can u please provide me switch case functionality